# Filter for hits on two arrays in RethinkDB ReQL?

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

Given the table `checkpointAttempts`, with schema:

```
{ 
  id: primary_key,
  userId: secondary_key & index,
  checkpointId: secondary_key & index
}
```

I'm trying to find all of the `checkpointAttempts` matching both an array of `userIds` and an array of `checkpointIds` at runtime.

I thought it might work by doing this:

```
// var userIds and checkpointIds are defined arrays & in scope

var q = r.table("checkpointAttempts");
q = q.getAll.apply(q, userIds.concat({index: userId}))
  .filter(function(attempt){
    return checkpointIds.indexOf(attempt('checkpointId')) !== -1
  })
  .run(conn)
```

But, `filter`'s predicate function seems to always return false.

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong, or how I might construct this query differently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use raw JavaScript such as `indexOf` inside filter function. You have to use ReQL expression and function.

On `getAll`, you can to simply wrap all arguments with `args`, and remove the need of `apply` to pass argument as an array.

The right query is like this:

```
r.table('checkpointAttempts')
  .getAll(r.args(userIds), {index: 'userId'})
  .filter(function(attempt){
    return r.expr(checkpointIds).contains(attempt('checkpointId')).eq(true)
  })
```

Just want to post some JS code here to help you get a clear idea:

```
var r = require('rethinkdb')

userIds = [1,2]
checkpointIds = [14, 12]

r.connect().then(function(conn) {
  return r.table('checkpointAttempts')
  .getAll(r.args(userIds),{index: 'userId'})
  .filter(function(attempt){
    return r.expr(checkpointIds).contains(attempt('checkpointId')).eq(true)
  })
  .run(conn)
})
.then(function(cursor) {
  return cursor.toArray()
})
.then(function(d) {
  console.log(d)
})
```